# Can my animal have scales?

Tags: xenobiology, fauna

I'm still figuring out the details but:

- it is about the size of a shoebox
- it is more mammalian than reptilian
- lives in trees
- lives in a hot climate
- warm-blooded
- will probably lay eggs
- it will probably eat bugs as a baby and then squirrel-like creatures when it's older
- It will be similar to a margay but with some reptilian features.

However, I think that scales would be better than fur.
I read that they help keep water in, camouflage, and can give traction to the animal.
I couldn't find any reasons for it to not have scales.

Are there any I missed?
And how would scales affect the cat's large ears?

Comment: How cat-like? Does it produce milk? Does it lay eggs? Can it control its bodily temperature? Elaborating on whether it works more like a cat-shaped reptile or as a mammal covered in scales can change a few things.

Comment: [Plenty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangolin) of [mammals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillo) have [scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse), at least on part of their body. [Some of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaver) are semiaquatic.

Comment: Would scales on its ears affect its hearing?

Comment: @ProjectApex sorry, I'm still figuring out the details but it's going to be more mammalian than reptilian. It's warm-blooded, will probably lay eggs, and I think, if possible, it will eat bugs as a baby and then squirrel-like creatures when it's older. It will be similar to a margay but with some reptilian features.

Comment: @StarSeeker I see. It'd be ideal if you could add what you told me in your question so others can also make sure to take those into consideration even if they don't read the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've described a [synapsid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synapsid) (or something very similar to it):

> ...modern and extinct synapsids possess a variety of modified skin coverings, including osteoderms (bony armor embedded in the skin), scutes (protective structures of the dermis often with a horny covering), hair or fur, and scale-like structures (often formed from modified hair, as in pangolins and some rodents).

They also displayed combinations of the other traits you've specified (in the edited version), and so would fit into this clade easily.